# What are the various upgradeable attributes?

Tags: swapquest

When I visit the enchantress in SwapQuest, I can upgrade the traits of my weapon and armor.  Unfortunately, I have no idea what any of these icons mean.

What are all of these attributes?

[image: SwapQuest upgrade screen]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm the developer of SwapQuest and will gladly answer your question.
The icons are (from top to bottom):

1. Poison: Damages the enemy/hero every few seconds for a short amount of time
2. Paralysis: Prevents the enemy/hero from attacking or moving from time to time
3. Confusion: Sometimes the enemy hits itself. If the hero is confused, you can't control him/her anymore
4. Blindness: Attacks often miss when you're blind
5. Absorption: Damages the enemy and gives you some health back

When you enchant your weapon, your chance of inflicting this effect increases, on your armor you have a better chance of avoiding that effect.

You can also read more info about every part of the caravan by pushing the ?-button at the top right in the respective area.

I hope that helped. Have fun with the game! :)

Constantin